# Convert Data Table To List<T> (list of model classes) Generic method performance

Tags: c#, entity-framework, generics, ado.net

I am using ADO.NET over Entity Framework to get high performance as data complexity of my application is bit high. Hence confused with below two approaches:

**Approach 1 - Generic Method For all**

I am using below generic method for converting data table to appropriate model object. Here it uses reflection and matches all properties of model with data table headers for map and build appropriate list.

```
#region ConvertToList
        /// <summary>
        /// DataTableToList ---  This function is used to Convert DataTable to List
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(DataTable dtDataCollection) where T : new()
        {
            var objList = new List<T>();

            //Define what attributes to be read from the class
            const BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance;

            //Read Attribute Names and Types
            var objFieldNames = typeof(T).GetProperties(flags).Cast<PropertyInfo>().
                Select(item => new
                {
                    Name = item.Name.ToLower(),
                    Type = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(item.PropertyType) ?? item.PropertyType
                }).ToList();

            //Read Datatable column names and types
            var dtlFieldNames = dtDataCollection.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                Select(item => new
                {
                    Name = item.ColumnName.ToLower(),
                    Type = item.DataType
                }).ToList();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dtDataCollection.AsEnumerable().ToList())
            {
                var classObj = new T();

                foreach (var dtField in dtlFieldNames)
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfos = classObj.GetType().GetProperty(dtField.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

                    var field = objFieldNames.Find(x => x.Name == dtField.Name);

                    if (field != null)
                    {

                        if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(DateTime))
                        {
                            propertyInfos.SetValue
                            (classObj, convertToDateTime(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                        }
                        else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(int))
                        {
                            propertyInfos.SetValue
                            (classObj, ConvertToInt(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                        }
                        else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(long))
                        {
                            propertyInfos.SetValue
                            (classObj, ConvertToLong(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                        }
                        else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(decimal))
                        {
                            propertyInfos.SetValue
                            (classObj, ConvertToDecimal(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                        }
                        else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(Boolean))
                        {
                            propertyInfos.SetValue
                            (classObj, ConvertToBool(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                        }
                        else if (propertyInfos.PropertyType == typeof(String))
                        {
                            if (dataRow[dtField.Name].GetType() == typeof(DateTime))
                            {
                                propertyInfos.SetValue
                                (classObj, ConvertToDateString(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                propertyInfos.SetValue
                                (classObj, ConvertToString(dataRow[dtField.Name]), null);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                objList.Add(classObj);
            }
            return objList;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToDateString ---   This function is used to convert object to DateString
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static string ConvertToDateString(object dtValue)
        {
            if (dtValue == null && dtValue == DBNull.Value)
                return string.Empty;

            //return SpecialDateTime.ConvertDate(Convert.ToDateTime(date));
            return Convert.ToString(dtValue);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToString --- This function is used to convert object to string              
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>


        private static string ConvertToString(object strValue)
        {
            // return Convert.ToString(HelperFunctions.ReturnEmptyIfNull(value));
            string returnValue = string.Empty;
            if (strValue != null && strValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToString(strValue);
            return returnValue;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToInt --- This function is used to convert object to Int            
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static int ConvertToInt(object iValue)
        {
            //return Convert.ToInt32(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
            int returnValue = 0;
            if (iValue != null && iValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToInt32(iValue);
            return returnValue;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToLong ---This function is used to convert object to Long
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static long ConvertToLong(object lngValue)
        {
            //return Convert.ToInt64(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
            Int64 returnValue = 0;
            if (lngValue != null && lngValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToInt64(lngValue);
            return returnValue;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToDecimal --- This function is used to convert object to Decimal
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static decimal ConvertToDecimal(object decValue)
        {
            //return Convert.ToDecimal(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
            decimal returnValue = 0;
            if (decValue != null && decValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToDecimal(decValue);
            return returnValue;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// DateTime --- This function is used to convert object to convertToDateTime
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static DateTime? convertToDateTime(object dtValue)
        {
            // return Convert.ToDateTime(HelperFunctions.ReturnDateTimeMinIfNull(date));
            DateTime? returnValue = null;
            if (dtValue != null && dtValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToDateTime(dtValue);
            return returnValue;
        }



        /// <summary>
        /// ConvertToBool ---This function is used to convert object to Bool
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>

        private static bool ConvertToBool(object blValue)
        {
            //return Convert.ToDecimal(HelperFunctions.ReturnZeroIfNull(value));
            bool returnValue = false;
            if (blValue != null && blValue != DBNull.Value)
                returnValue = Convert.ToBoolean(blValue);
            return returnValue;
        }
        #endregion ConvertToList
```

**Approach 2 - By Manual mapping like below**

Manual mapping to model object from data table. In this approach we need to write this method for **every mapping.**

```
List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();  
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)  
{  
    Student student = new Student();  
    student.StudentId = Convert .ToInt32 (dt.Rows[i]["StudentId"]);  
    student.StudentName = dt.Rows[i]["StudentName"].ToString();  
    student.Address = dt.Rows[i]["Address"].ToString();  
    student.MobileNo = dt.Rows[i]["MobileNo"].ToString();  
    studentList.Add(student);  
}
```

**My Question -** Is this generic way of conversion makes impact on performance? Should I switch to normal manual mapping of objects like **Approach 2**? Is **Approach 2** enhancing the performance ?

Comment: Sure it makes impact on perfomance. You should just decide if that impact is acceptable in your case. You can also use perfomance-oriented ORMs (like Dapper) which will do that dynamic conversion for you (and most likely much better than in provided code example).

Comment: Well accessing everything via reflection is likely to be a lot slower, yes. Whether that's significant in your application is a different matter. Note that there are already plenty of mapping libraries available - I suspect one of them will do what you need, and they're likely to be considerably more optimized than your current code.

Comment: you can try use AutoMapper (http://automapper.org/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer Yes/No would not be precise.

What you need to do is to measure numbers. I recommend using performance measurement tools like dotTrace.

1. Create test cases for mapping single table with many rows, many small tables and table with many columns.
2. Run benchmark of reflection-based generic and manual methods

This would give you precise numbers of how much time you are winning using manual mapping and what are bottlenecks of generic methods.

If your win is small (lets say 10-20% of time) or works only in specific case, usage of manual mapping is not worth efforts.

Also it may help you discover weak spots of you generic method. For example discovering property

```
PropertyInfo propertyInfos = classObj.GetType().GetProperty(dtField.Name, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
```

May be moved one level up and moved to hash table. Discovering properties for each row may be overkill.